# django-ckeditor failing due to template path problem

Tags: django, ckeditor

I just added django-ckeditor to my django project by installing it:

```
pip install django-ckeditor
```

adding it to `INSTALLED_APPS`, adding the upload path:

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "ckeditor_uploads/"
```

run `manage.py collecstatic` which only added two files, and adding the URLs to my `url.py`:

```
url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
```

I'm not 100% sure if I'm not missing something there.

Then I created a very simple model that looks like this:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    body = RichTextField(blank=False, null=False)
```

When I try to add a new record on the admin tool I get this error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/core/blogpost/add/
>
> ckeditor/widget.html

The template loader postmortem looks like this:

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\pupeno\projectx\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\templates\ckeditor\widget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\pupeno\projectx\core\templates\ckeditor\widget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\pupeno\projectx\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\ckeditor\widget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\pupeno\projectx\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\ckeditor\widget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\pupeno\projectx\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templates\ckeditor\widget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\pupeno\projectx\venv\lib\site-packages\reversion\templates\ckeditor\widget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\pupeno\projectx\venv\lib\site-packages\colorfield\templates\ckeditor\widget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\pupeno\projectx\venv\lib\site-packages\ckeditor_uploader\templates\ckeditor\widget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\pupeno\projectx\venv\lib\site-packages\django_extensions\templates\ckeditor\widget.html (Source does not exist)
```

The line before the last one is relevant, it's trying to load `ckeditor/widget.html` from `ckeditor_uploader` but `widget.html` is present in `ckeditor`, not `ckeditor_uploader`:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here?

I also tried turning the field into a `RichTextUploadingField`, but I've got the same error.

Comment: I have the same problem. The answers  are refers INSTALLED_APPS and suggests adding `ckeditor` and `ckeditor_uploader` however I am getting same error yet.

Answer (score 14):

The problem was that I added `ckeditor_uploader` and not `ckeditor` to the installed apps.

Comment: I think you forgot to add this as the accepted answer

Comment: In the end I needed both `ckeditor` and `ckeditor_uploader` and to run `manage.py collectstatic` to get the page for `Browse Server` to render, because it's a functionality related to `ckeditor_uploader` specifically

Answer (score 3):

Even I faced the same issue. Please follow my steps. it will work for me as well as many of my friends also.

Remember it will also work for **production level** as i hosted many django application in online.

pip install django-ckeditor

after

**step 1:** write inside models.py

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    body = RichTextField(blank=False, null=False)
```

**step 2:** run command **python manage.py makemigrations**

**step 3:** run command **python manage.py migrate**

**step 4:** write in admin.py

```
from .models import BlogPost
admin.site.register(BlogPost)
```

**step 4:** I added **"ckeditor"** in installed_apps of settings.py.

**step 5:** run command **python manage.py collectstatic**

It will ask you to **overrite Existing** files and type **yes**

make sure your directory structure look like

[image: make sure your directory structure look like]

**step 6:** Copy ckeditor folder in root static folder where your control panel looks for

In my case i have to copy ckditor folder in another called **public_html**

I coppied ckeditor folder in **public_html/static/**

[image]

**All done**

Answer (score 2):

You need both apps in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'ckeditor',
  'ckeditor_uploader'
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I added ckeditor to the installed apps of the settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue.
After reading docs I had added "**ckeditor_uploader**" in *urls.py* and in *installed_apps*.

Then finally realized and added only "**ckeditor**" in *installed_apps* of *settings.py* and "**ckeditor_uploader**" in *urls.py*